# Селект данных из базы на страничку в виде ссылок

Tags: php

Есть sql-база, в ней таблица "*builds*" с полем "*bazaname*".

Нужно произвести выборку из БД значений поля "bazaname" и вывести в столбец. При нажатии на одно из значений оно должно быть записано в переменную `$aktivbazaname`

С выборкой проблем нет, проблема с записью значения в переменную.

Пример:

```
<?php 
session_start();
include ("bd.php");

// выбираем значениt из таблицы "builds"
$qr_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `builds` WHERE 1 LIMIT 0, 30 ")
or die(mysql_error());
// выводим на страницу сайта заголовки HTML-таблицы
echo '<table border="0">';
echo '<thead>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th> <span style="font-family: &quot;Arial&quot;;"><span style="font-size:      9pt;"><strong>Ваши базы</strong></span></span></th>';
echo '</tr>';
echo '</thead>';
echo '<tbody>';

// выводим в HTML-таблицу  данные из таблицы MySQL 
while($data = mysql_fetch_array($qr_result)){ 
echo "<td><a name=\"del\" href=\"operation.php\">$data[bazaname]</a></td>\n";

echo '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
 }

echo '</tbody>';
echo '</table>';

// закрываем соединение с сервером  базы данных
mysql_close($connect_to_db);
?>
```

Дальше зашел в тупик. нужно присвоить переменной *$aktivbazaname* то значение, по котором кликнул пользователь из выбранного списка

Comment: Разберитесь с тем как работает клиент-сервеные приложения, вам поможет GET/POST запросы.
http://phpfaq.ru/na_tanke

Comment: @Николай12g4, Оформляйте вопросы согласно правилам сообщества, иначе они будут удаляться. Пожалуйста, приведите код вместо ссылки на изображение.